# Cumulating lcov outputs for different absolute directories

Tags: gitlab-ci, lcov

I'm using code coverage on different test suites and those suites are launched under different directories.
Say my suite1 is launched in directory `/path1/mysoft/src` and my suite2 is launched in directory `/path2/mysoft/src/`

I launch lcov in `/path1/mysoft` (respectively with `path2`) using `lcov -d . -c -o suite1.info` (resp. with `suite2`).

Then I want to cumulate the coverage from both test suites. I copy the `suite1.info` and `suite2.info` files in another directory `/path3/mysoft` which also contains the source code from my program.

I can cumulate both with `lcov -a suite1.info -a suite2.info -o tests.info` however the coverage for a given file `src/example.c` won't be cumulated as `lcov` will condider that `/path1/mysoft/src/example.c` and `/path2/mysoft/src/example.c` are two different files. Therefore cumulating won't work.

**How can I cumulate code coverage for the same source code coming from different base directories?**

Some unsatistfying solutions

- Removing the base directories by launching `lcov -d . -c --rc geninfo_adjust_src_path=/path1 -o suite1.info`. In this case the coverage will be cumulated correctly by `lcov`, however `genhtml` will fail because it won't find the source code at the correct place. At this time I don't know what `path3` will be, so I can't replace `path1` by `path3`.
- Renaming the base directories when cumulating `lcov` outputs by using the same `geninfo_adjust_src_path` option. I've been unable to do so: launching `lcov -a suite1.info -a suite2.info --rc geninfo_adjust_src_path='path1 => path3' --rc geninfo_adjust_src_path='path1 => path2'  -o tests.info` didn't change anything.
- Launching everying in the same base directory (see below)

**Some context**

Why am I launching my test suites in different base directories? Well actually the continuous integration is doing that. So `path1` is something like `/home/gitlab/builds/b8e873c2/0/`. The test suites are each launched in a different job and cumulating the coverage is also done in another job. Each job is launched in a different base directory and the `.info` files are retrieved using artifacts.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an answer, that may not be the most elegant. As source filenames are stored in plain text, they can be changed pretty easily using `sed` for instance.

Therefore all the commands launched could look like this (remind that each is actually launched by a different job):

`lcov -d . -c --rc geninfo_adjust_src_path=/path1 -o suite1.info # in /path1/mysoft
lcov -d . -c --rc geninfo_adjust_src_path=/path2 -o suite2.info # in /path2/mysoft
 # From /path3/mysoft, after retrieving suite1.info and suite2.info
lcov -a suite1.info -a suite2.info | sed 's/^SF:/mysoft/SF:/path3/mysoft' > tests.info`

The two firt lines remove any reference to `/path1` or `/path2` from the `.info` files. The third line adds a reference to `/path3` in front of the path to the source files so that the genhtml can find them.